# Hybris -> how to create cronjob with execute beanshell script?

Tags: groovy, beanshell, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a beanshell script and I would like it to automate. 
I need to create cronjob and add my beanshell code to it. 
Maybe someone do that think? 
Is anyone know how to do this?
or how to match my script with cronjob?

Comment: Which hybris version are you using? The solution in my answer works for Hybris v5.7.

Comment: Try this : https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/use-scripting-job-in-sap-hybris/

Answer (score 2):

The answer is actually given in [Cronjob scripting](https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8b9d40fa86691014b471f5bf5a9715dd.html) documentation.

In a nutshell, you will use dynamic scripting to create the cronjob instead of using the slow old-fashioned way.

---

### Concept

There are three new objects used (quoted from doc):

> - Script - the item type where the script content is stored (a separate deployment table)
> - ScriptingJob - a new ServicelayerJob item, which contains additionally the scriptURI (consequently, the stored script can be
>     found at runtime from different locations (classpath, db, etc..)
> - ScriptingJobPerformable - the spring bean assigned to every ScriptingJob instance; it implements the usual perform() method (like
>     for any other cronjob). This is where the "scripted" cronjob logic is
>     executed

---

### How to use Cronjob scripting

**First step** -  save your Script instance in the database. For this example I've used a code from http://www.beanshell.org/manual/quickstart.html

> Note: you can create script with Groovy, BeanShell ad JavaScript

```
INSERT_UPDATE Script; code[unique=true];content;scriptType(code)
;myBshScript;"foo = ""Foo"";    
four = (2 + 2)*2/2;
print( foo + "" = "" + four );  // print() is a BeanShell command

// Do a loop
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    print(i);   

// Pop up a frame with a button in it
button = new JButton( ""My Button"" );
frame = new JFrame( ""My Frame"" );
frame.getContentPane().add( button, ""Center"" );
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);";BEANSHELL
```

> Don't forget to escape `"` in the script with an other `"` (Impex restriction).

**Second step** - create a ScriptingJob that use the previously created Script

```
INSERT_UPDATE ScriptingJob; code[unique=true];scriptURI
;myBshDynamicJob;model://myBshScript
```

> `model://myBshScript` is used to retrieve a Script stored in the DB

**Third step** - create the CronJob

```
INSERT_UPDATE CronJob; code[unique=true];job(code);singleExecutable;sessionLanguage(isocode)
;myBshDynamicCronJob;myBshDynamicJob;true;en
```

**Optional step** - create a trigger for the CronJob

```
INSERT_UPDATE Trigger;cronjob(code)[unique=true];cronExpression
;myBshDynamicCronJob;0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *
```

> This executes the cronjob every hour.

**Execute the CronJob by script**

In the hac scripting tab, choose Groovy and run this in commit mode.

```
def dynamicCJ = cronJobService.getCronJob("myBshDynamicCronJob")
cronJobService.performCronJob(dynamicCJ,true)
```

After running the Script you should have this displayed

[image]

And in the console

```
INFO  [hybrisHTTP27] (myBshDynamicCronJob) [ScriptingJobPerformable] Foo = 4
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

In Hybris, go to HMC> System> CronJobs> Search your created cronjob or create a new cronjob> Time Schedule tab> Trigger> Create Trigger.

From this Trigger tab window, you can schedule the interval eg. daily, weekly, etc. Also you can set the start time and frequency.

You can also do this trigger setting via impex as below:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Trigger;cronJob(code)[unique=true];second;minute;hour;day;month;year;relative;active;maxAcceptableDelay
;CartRemovalJob;0;5;4;-1;-1;-1;false;true;-1
```

For more detailed information, have a look at [this](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/Trail+~+CronJobs), in case you have access to Hybris Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to hybris wiki, [here](https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=294094189) you can find how to create and execute a cronjob.

In order to execute bean shell, in the cronjob "perform" method you should do this:

```
SimpleScriptContent content = new SimpleScriptContent("beanshell", "here your beanshell script code as string");
ScriptExecutable script = scriptingLanguagesService.getExecutableByContent(content);
ScriptExecutionResult result = script.execute();
...
```

Here the import section:

```
import de.hybris.platform.scripting.engine.content.impl.SimpleScriptContent;
import de.hybris.platform.scripting.engine.ScriptExecutionResult;
import de.hybris.platform.scripting.engine.ScriptExecutable;
```

You should access to scriptingLanguagesService with annotation:

```
@Autowired
ScriptingLanguagesService scriptingLanguagesService;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below steps for the groovy script. You can try the same for the beanshell.

---

You have to create an instance of

**Script** - the item type where the script content is going to store.

**ScriptingJob** - a new ServicelayerJob item, which contains additionally the scriptURI

**CronJob** - This is where the "scripted" cronjob logic is executed

---

**1. Create a Script**

*Script code:* `HelloScript`
*Script engine type:* `beanshell`
*Content:* `log.info("Hello");`

**2. Create the Scripting Job**

Again from HMC/Backoffice, find ScriptinJobs and create the new instance of it. Here you have to define `Code` and `ScriptURI` like

*Code:* `HelloScriptJob`
*ScriptURI:* `model://HelloScript`

You can access this job in the next step to create the CronJob

**3. Create a CronJob**

From HMC/BackOffice, create an instance of cronJob. Select above-created job(HelloScriptJob) in
`Job definition` drops down and save the changes. Now you good to schedule/run this cronJob.

---

Refer detailed post [cronjob-using-groovy-script-hybris](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/07/cronjob-using-groovy-script-hybris.html)